# TapGestureRecognizer doesn’t work for Span inside Label in MAUI .NET

Tags: c#, .net, maui

`TapGestureRecognizer` doesn’t work for Span inside Label(FormattedText). `Command` is not firing, even `Tapped` is not firing.
I am using `<TargetFrameworks>net7.0-android;net7.0-ios;net7.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>`

Below is my XAML:

```
<Label LineHeight="1.3" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center">
                <Label.FormattedText>
                    <FormattedString>
                        <Span Text="Read our " />                  
                        <local:HyperlinkSpan Text="Privacy Policy"
                                         Url="https://www.eurycele.com" />
                        
                        <Span Text=". Tap &quot;Agree and continue&quot; to accept the " />
                        
                        <local:HyperlinkSpan Text="Terms of Service"
                                         Url="https://www.eurycele.com" />
                        <Span Text="Terms of Service"
                              TextColor="Blue">
                            <Span.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TapCommand}"
                                                      CommandParameter="https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/"  />
                            </Span.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Span> 
                        <Span Text="." />
                    </FormattedString>
                </Label.FormattedText>
            </Label>
```

`local:HyperlinkSpan` is taken from https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/main/UserInterface/Hyperlinks/HyperlinkDemo/HyperlinkSpan.cs

I have already tried below approached:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/label
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-hyperlinks/

Please suggest.

Comment: Add to question code: 1) that declares `TapCommand`. 2) that sets `BindingContext` of the page this XAML is in. 3) TapCommand must be in whatever class the BIndingContext is set to (either `this`, or some viewmodel). Since nothing is happening, look in VS Output pane when app runs. Is there any warning that mentiond `TapCommand`? If so, add to question the text of that warning.

Comment: I am getting `[AutofillManager] requestHideFillUi(null): anchor = null` whenever I am using with phone

Comment: Sounds to me like TapCommand runs, but there is a problem with its code. If you put a breakpoint on first line of TapCommand, does VS stop at that breakpoint?

Comment: is that a runtime exception?  A compiler error?  A console message?

Comment: No, breakpoint never get hit. I tried every approach but somehow breakpoint is not getting hit. This is not a runtime exception, it is simple a log from debug window.  My code is simple copy pasted from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/label. When it didn't work I tried with custom code approach https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-hyperlinks/

Comment: As mentioned here https://github.com/dotnet/docs-maui/issues/1605:
This is due to a bug in .NET MAUI - see dotnet/maui#8004. AFAIK, it's been fixed but I suspect the fix is only targeting the .NET 8 release.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue on my side, and it is a known issue about `Span.GestureRecognizers` that it doesn’t work for `Span` inside `Label` in MAUI .NET

You can follow it here: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4734.

As an alternative workaround, you can use `Label.GestureRecognizers` rather than `Span.GestureRecognizers` like below:

```
<Label Text="Terms of Service" 
       TextColor="Blue" 
       LineHeight="1.3" 
       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"> 
       
      <Label.GestureRecognizers>
               <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TapCommand}"                                     CommandParameter="https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/"  />
       </Label.GestureRecognizers>
</Label>
```

Update:

This is due to a potential issue in .NET MAUI, see [dotnet/maui#8004](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8004).AFAIK, it will be fixed which is targeting the .NET 8 release.

Comment: Thank you @Alexandar. I too stumble upon this and I can see that the fix will be available in `fixed-in-8.0.0-preview.5.8529` version.

Comment: As mentioned here https://github.com/dotnet/docs-maui/issues/1605:
This is due to a bug in .NET MAUI - see dotnet/maui#8004. AFAIK, it's been fixed but I suspect the fix is only targeting the .NET 8 release.

Comment: Hi @Alexandar,  Can you please try to answer this question too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76787581/place-button-to-the-bottom-right-corner-of-the-phone-as-fixed-position-in-net-m  if you have time?

Answer (score 1):

this works for me

```
<Label LineHeight="1.3" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center">
            <Label.FormattedText>
                <FormattedString>
                    <Span Text="Read our " />                  
                    
                    <Span Text=". Tap &quot;Agree and continue&quot; to accept the " />
                    
                   
                    <Span Text="Terms of Service"
                          TextColor="Blue">
                        <Span.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TapCommand}"
                                                  CommandParameter="https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/"  />
                        </Span.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Span> 
                    <Span Text="." />
                </FormattedString>
            </Label.FormattedText>
        </Label>
```

and

```
    public ICommand TapCommand { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        TapCommand = new Command<string>((arg) => DisplayAlert("Message", arg, "OK"));

        BindingContext = this;
    }
```

Comment: I am getting `[AutofillManager] requestHideFillUi(null): anchor = null` whenever I am using Phone with above code

Comment: Hi Jason,  Can you please try to answer this question too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76787581/place-button-to-the-bottom-right-corner-of-the-phone-as-fixed-position-in-net-m  if you have time?

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been confirmed to be fixed in .NET8 preview 7 on Android, but not on Windows and iOS.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Another work around for this would be to create a button with a Color of Transparency that you add over the top and that'll get the clicks on IOS at least.

Answer (score -1):

Workaround for this is to add `TapGestureRecognizer` for label too. Then span command will work.

```xml
<Label
    x:Name="consentLabel"
    Grid.Row="2">
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <Span
                Text="{Binding TextLink[0]}" />
            <Span
                FontAttributes="Bold"
                Text="Privacy policy"
                TextDecorations="Underline">
                <Span.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding PrivacyPolicyTapCommand}" />
                </Span.GestureRecognizers>
            </Span>
            <Span
                Text="{Binding TextLink[2]}" />
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" />
    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
</Label>
```

And leave `TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped` method empty. There's nothing to add.