# Place Button to the Bottom Right Corner of the Phone as Fixed position in .Net MAUI

Tags: c#, android, ios, maui

How can I place Button to the Bottom Right Corner of the phone as Fixed position in .Net MAUI so that it is above the ScrollView content, like we use to do `position:"fixed", bottom:"20px", right:"20px"` in web application using CSS.

[image]

Till Now My Xaml look like this:

```xml
<VerticalStackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <!--Title View-->
    <Grid BackgroundColor="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}" ColumnDefinitions="150, *" HeightRequest="50" 
          VerticalOptions="Center" Padding="5,0,15,0">
        <Label Style="{StaticResource BrandLabelWhite}" Margin="0,0,0,0">Sample App</Label>

        <HorizontalStackLayout Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">

            <Image HeightRequest="22" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
                <Image.Source>
                    <FontImageSource FontFamily="FaIcons"
                                     Glyph="{x:Static fonts:FontAwesomeSolidIcons.EllipsisVertical}"
                                     Size="30" Color="{StaticResource White}"/>
                </Image.Source>
            </Image>
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
    </Grid>

    <ScrollView>
        <Label>Some text</Label>
    </ScrollView>

    <AbsoluteLayout FlexLayout.AlignSelf="End">
        <Button Style="{StaticResource PrimaryButton}"              
            HeightRequest="60" WidthRequest="60"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,60,60"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
            CornerRadius="50">
            <Button.ImageSource>
                <FontImageSource FontFamily="FaIcons"
                                     Glyph="{x:Static fonts:FontAwesomeSolidIcons.Plus}"
                                     Size="20" Color="{StaticResource White}"/>
            </Button.ImageSource>
        </Button>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

You can ignore the IconFonts that are used in button. I also tried with `FlexLayout, Position="Absolute"` but position absolute reference is not available in [Microsoft Docs For FlexLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/flexlayout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. There are a couple of way to do this depending on what you are going to do with that particular page. This is flex in a grid that might be what you want.

```xml
    <Grid Margin="10,0" RowDefinitions="Auto,*">
        <VerticalStackLayout VerticalOptions="Start">
            <!--  Title View  -->
            <Grid
                Grid.Row="0"
                Padding="5,0,15,0"
                BackgroundColor="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}"
                ColumnDefinitions="150, *"
                HeightRequest="50"
                VerticalOptions="Center">
                <HorizontalStackLayout Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="End">
                    <Image
                        HeightRequest="22"
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        VerticalOptions="Center">
                        <Image.Source>
                            <FontImageSource
                                FontFamily="FaIcons"
                                Glyph="{x:Static fonts:FontAwesomeSolidIcons.EllipsisVertical}"
                                Size="30"
                                Color="{StaticResource White}" />
                        </Image.Source>
                    </Image>
                </HorizontalStackLayout>
            </Grid>

            <ScrollView>
                <Label>Some text</Label>
            </ScrollView>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
        <FlexLayout
            Grid.Row="1"
            AlignItems="End"
            JustifyContent="End"
            Wrap="NoWrap">
            <Button
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,60,60"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                CornerRadius="50"
                HeightRequest="60"
                Style="{StaticResource PrimaryButton}"
                WidthRequest="60">
                <Button.ImageSource>
                    <FontImageSource
                        FontFamily="FaIcons"
                        Glyph="{x:Static fonts:FontAwesomeSolidIcons.Plus}"
                        Size="20"
                        Color="{StaticResource White}" />
                </Button.ImageSource>
            </Button>

        </FlexLayout>

    </Grid>
```

[image: Phone layout]

Comment: After few tweaks.. That really helped.. Thank you. :)